# Not able to submit Instagram App for App Review

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

My application uses Instagram API (old version, as new Instagram Graph API supports only business accounts, which is not viable in my case), thus I created application on https://www.instagram.com/developer and now, as application is finished I want to apply for app review to go live. However, button for submitting application is disabled without any explanation.

Has anyone encountered similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Starting October 15, 2019, new client registration and permission review on Instagram API platform are discontinued in favor of the Instagram Basic Display API.